# Read file and generate query in plsql oracle 11

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I am writing a stored procedure where I have to do following: I want to have a file (any format properties, json, xml) which will have information of which columns I want to extract from my table.

For example: my table has columns `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`, and suppose my `file.properties` has below information

```
A=1
B=0
C=1
D=1
F=0
```

So my generated query should be `Select A,C,D from my table;`

How can I do this in Oracle 11G?

Comment: what did you try? and what is the problem that you can't solve?

Comment: my current solution is very ugly..I have created a file.txt with A boolean := true; .B boolean := true; ...and so on  and in my procedure.sql file i have special text REPLACE_TEXT_WITH VARIABLE  and bunch of if statements like if A then  
      l_query := l_query || ' A, ';
    end if;  to generate query variable and so first i sed the text with the content of file.txt and execute the procedure.sql.

Comment: I am looking for some clean approach

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> create or replace procedure pr_dynamic_sql( v_result out sys_refcursor ) is
    v_outfile  utl_file.file_type;
    v_path     varchar2(100) := 'UTL_FILE_DIR'; 
                            -- alias for the directory where your text files generated at OS.
    v_row      varchar2(100);
    v_file     varchar2(100);
    v_letter   varchar2(10);
    v_number   varchar2(10);
    v_sql      varchar2(100):= 'select ';
begin
    v_file    := 'myfile.properties';
    v_outfile := utl_file.fopen(v_path, v_file, 'r');
  loop
   begin 
     utl_file.get_line(v_outfile,v_row); 
     v_letter := regexp_substr(v_row,'[^=]');
     v_number := substr(regexp_substr(v_row,'[^=]+$'),1,1); 

    if v_number = '1' then
      v_sql := v_sql||v_letter||',';
    end if;             
   exception when no_data_found then exit;
   end; 
  end loop;
    utl_file.fclose(v_outfile); 
    v_sql := rtrim(v_sql,',')||' from mytable'; 
    open v_result for v_sql;
end;
```

and call

```
SQL> begin
  pr_dynamic_sql(v_result => :v_result);
end;
/
```

to get results as of cursor type.